# Get data based on different week start and end dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>name</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>last_name</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>email</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>start_date</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>end_date</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venky</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-06-25</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-01</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>asd</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-06-25</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-01</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>rakesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-06-25</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-01</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venkatesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-06-25</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-01</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>jhon</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-06-25</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-01</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venky</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-02</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-08</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>asd</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-02</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-08</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>rakesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-02</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-08</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venkatesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-02</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-08</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>jhon</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-02</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-08</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venky</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-09</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-15</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>asd</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-09</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-15</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>rakesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-09</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-15</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venkatesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-09</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-15</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>jhon</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-09</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-15</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venky</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-16</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-22</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>asd</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-16</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-22</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>rakesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>raki</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-16</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-22</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>venkatesh</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-16</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-22</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>jhon</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>sai</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>ascd@gmail.com</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-16</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2018-07-22</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

I have data like this. If I select Start_date:'2018-06-25' and end_date:'2018-07-01'. I should get data from that week. If select any start_date and end date in the week. I should get that weeks data. Example Start_date:'2018-06-28' and end_date:'2018-07-09'. If I select Start_date:'2018-06-25' and end_date:'2018-07-11'. I should get three weeks of data. Is this possible?

Comment: You need an SQL query to achieve that? Take a look at WHERE clause

Comment: I did but I am only getting one week of data. But if I want 3 or 4 weeks of data? how to do that and user may select any dates with in the week

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE start_date::date > '2018-06-25' and end_date::date < '2018-07-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of  `Start_date:'2018-06-28' and end_date:'2018-06-09'` you should use `>=` and `<=` in the `where` clause, it might look something like this:

```
select * from your_table where Start_date >= '2018-06-09' and end_date <= '2018-06-28'
```

Comment: I won't get any data if use this query. Because there are no rows with Start_date = '2018-06-28' and end_date = '2018-06-09'

Comment: @user1510963 thats why I used `>=` and `<=`  so its between those dates

Comment: This work only when start_date and end_date are on the same week. If both are from different weeks then it won't work. I tried but it is not woking